# How to display a server object variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am currently able to display an object that is sent from the server which looks like this:

```
 var tweets = {
 &#34;PaoIotics&#34;: [
        &#34;@JoshCannon99 @hanks_h @MCFC it&#39;s QPR. He&#39;s done nothing big since that other than 1 game vs Bayern.&#34;
    ],
    &#34;YadavDhital&#34;: [
        &#34;RT @ArronMCFC: @YadavDhital @MCFC cheers, for supporting city since 2008 +&#34;
    ],
    &#34;GoodKunManCity&#34;: [
        &#34;@Binky_Ferrari @stuff_mcfc @ManCityArmy1894 @cfcMode no I meant since he said failure isn&#39;t an option but look at this season lol&#34;
    ],
```

Now I want to modify this object so that it can be displayed nicely on  HTML page but I am unsure of how to do two things. First, is it possible to loop through the object and remove all the unwanted characters that have been added namely the `&#34;` that is shown instead of quotation marks. Secondly, what is the best way to change the object into a HTML table?

EDIT:

```
var tweets = <%= tweets %>;
for (var t in tweets) {
  var row = $('<row></row>');
  row.append('<th style="border:1px solid black">' + t + '</th><td style="border:1px solid black">' + tweets[t][0]+ '</td>');
  $("#tweetTable").append(row);
}
```

I have included the suggested code in my HTML script but it does not seem to work, the only error that is thrown is in relation to the characters in tweets

Comment: You don't want to get rid of the encoded characters. Instead, you want to _convert them back_ to their original representation.

Comment: There is something you could start with here: https://jsfiddle.net/tmzfwsyu/3/

Comment: Thanks for the responses I will have a look now

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I have tried to implement your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work. I have included your code in the script on the html page, in my javascript file and neither way seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to unescape your string (using `replace()` function) and then convert it to object (using `JSON.parse()`):

```
var tweets = <%= tweets %>;
var json = JSON.parse(tweets.replace(/&#34;/g, '\"'));

for (var t in json) {
  var row = $('<row></row>');
  row.append('<th style="border:1px solid black">' + t + '</th><td style="border:1px solid black">' + json[t][0]+ '</td>');
  $("#tweetTable").append(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this still doesn't seem to produce a table. The div containing tweetTable does not display any table

Comment: if you do console.log(json) do you have a valid javascript object?

Comment: Yes, I've even tried just using the example object i provided

Comment: so the problem is with your table html. See this working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tmzfwsyu/4/

Comment: I still can not get it to work as it does on jsfiddle, the HTML page can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Nb1c8uhd

Comment: You do for (var t in tweets) but you should do for (var t in json)

Comment: My bad! Although it still does not display a table with these changes

Comment: You also have to change tweets by json in the loop block

Comment: It appears that it is forming the rows as expected but it is not adding this to tweetTable

Comment: Maybe your <table> is not yet in the body when the code is runned. See it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/9yd0dz8n/1/

Comment: That was it, your a star mate thank you for the help